# xcode - correct use of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I defined in a SecondView a public property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)  NSMutableDictionary * ToModify;
```

From firseview, I used that property to passing another dicnary to dsecond view

```
secondView.ToModify =origin;
```

But when I try to modify the content of ToModify by setObject method, crash appears:

```
_NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

It seems that ToModify is a NSDictonary, and in fact by nslog class, it appears as NSDictonary.

Why it occurs?

Comment: what's `origin`? If it's an `NSDictionary`, you need to use `[origin mutableCopy]` in order to create an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: How can I init it from the first view? If I do itno secondView, "origin" content it lost

Comment: So this isn't a new property, but an overridden one? What is the actual name of the property, and what is `SecondView` a subclass of?

Can you post your actual code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler complains that `origin` is an immutable `NSDictionary.`

To make it mutable, call `mutableCopy`

```
secondView.ToModify = [origin mutableCopy];
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize a dictionary necessarily. Assigning another dictionary is valid, too @MorganHarris

Comment: Then surely he would be calling it on `self`, not `secondView`, in `[SecondView init]`?

edit: dammit I just realised I read your code totally wrong :P. second comment still stands. this should be done in init by SecondView.

Comment: Actually that doesn't affect the question *Why it occurs?* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring an object as NSMutableDictionary isn't enough - you have to *instantiate* it as an NSMutableDictionary. Where are you initialising `ToModify`?

At some point in `SecondView`, you currently have

```
self.ToModify = [[NSDictionary alloc] init]; //or something similar
```

which needs to be

```
self.ToModify = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

---

What actually is `SecondView`, and what's the actual purpose of `ToModify`? Are you overriding an existing property, or adding a new one?